# Visual Studio 2010 Hangs When Deploying Windows Phone App

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7.1

When deploying my Silverlight app, everything seems to be working until the screen goes black (just before the app starts loading) and Visual Studio gets to the "Launching UI Task" part of the build. Visual Studio is then unresponsive for about 60-90 seconds, during which time the screen remains black.

Finally, Visual Studio will become responsive again, the initial splash screen will load and the app will launch. However, it will hang again when I hit the "stop" button, this time for longer. It does this on a deploy to a device and to the emulator and it only does this for this one app (other projects deploy just fine).

It also does not hang when I do a non-deploy build. Cleaning and rebuilding the solution has no effect.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 SP1 (Version 10.0.40219.1 SP1Rel). If you think I'm missing any helpful information, please let me know.

Comment: same thing is happening to me, could you solve this problem?

Comment: I ended up deleting a number of extensions I wasn't using, including an Azure extension that I *think* was the problem but can't tell for sure. In retrospect, I should have deleted one at a time, but I was blind with tearful rage when I did the deletions.

Comment: Have you found a solution yet? All the sudden I am facing the same issue as you described... :( Atm I can only use Expression Blend to deploy to my device...

Comment: I'd start by deleting the SUO file as Scott Davis mentions below and see if that helps. If not, try deleting your extensions one at a time.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem as well.  I remembered from long ago I found a post that stated if there was an invalid breakpoint, startup time could take forever.  I deleted the .SUO file (which stores the breakpoints) and everything was back in order.